# Extract the line with the same content from two files in R

Tags: r

I would like to use readLines function to read the text file line by line

> 69C_t.txt

Also, I would like to write a simple for loop with condition to extract the identical lines in two files.

```
69C_t <- "69C_t.txt"
conn <- file(69C_t,open="r")
t <-readLines(conn)
69C_b <- "69C_b.txt"
conn <- file(69C_b,open="r")
b <-readLines(conn)
for (i in 1:length(t)){
  for (j in 1:length(b)){
    if (i==j)
    write(t[i], file = "overlap.txt")
  }
}
close(tumor)
```

However, it seems only print out the first line. 
Can someone please have a check ?

Comment: You are comparing `i` and `j`, not `t[i]` and `b[j]`.  If you are writing a file in  this way, you should open a `con` first, and close it at the end of the loop, otherwise it will overwrite it each time.

Comment: @AndrewGustar you are completely right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A faster approach would be, instead of the loop

```
writeLines(t[t %in% b],"overlap.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding append in the write function:
    write(t[i], file = "overlap.txt", append = TRUE)

Comment: yes, it should be if (b[j]==t[i]) and write(b[j], file = "overlapping.txt", append = TRUE)